# Applying AOP to a 3-tier winforms application

Tags: winforms, aop, 3-tier

**Background**

I am trying to implement logging and exception handling using AOP for a new project. 
I wish to apply this through all the 3 layers of a Windows form application. 
I am using Windsor Castle as the container.

I have successfully applied logging through AOP to a very simple example. 
But scaling it to a winforms application is proving difficult.

**Problem**

I managed to register the main form in the container and apply the logging aspect as well.
But the aspect is being hit for all events w.r.t winforms. 
(eg: get_ForeColor, get_BackColor, OnControlAdded, DefWndProc, DestroyHandle..etc)

The events and methods that i actually need logging for are not showing up in the log file(aspect). 
What am i doing wrong here. Is an interface implementation always necessary for AOP?

I would also like to know what the framework (or architecture) should look like with AOP.
How and where should the registration of all components from  3 layers take place. 
Should it be at application start up? Links to any examples will be very helpful.

**PS:** This is the first time i am trying to implement AOP. To add to it i have to code in vb.net which i am not very comfortable with.
Also i cannot use Post Sharp (funds are an issue).

Comment: since you're using Castle Windsor, does that mean you are using Castle DynamicProxy for AOP?

Comment: @mgroves: i am using Castle.DynamicProxy for AOP. I am new to using containers as well, so was not quite sure when i answered you the first time.